# Why does consecutive fgets accept input but stores it as a different or blank data when printed in a loop?

Tags: c, fgets

I'm a beginner at coding and I'm having trouble with using fgets because it accepts the input that I place but when I try to output it using printf then it isn't the right input.

I'm sorry if the answer is obvious but I've been stuck on this problem for an hour.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int eh;
    char name[32];
    char idnum[32];
    char coursename[9][20];
    int numberofcourses;
    int unit[9];
    float grade[9];
}information;

int main(){
    char id[32];
    char course_name[12];
    information info[21];
    char buf[3];
    int numberofstud;
    printf("Enter Number of Students:");
    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
    sscanf(buf, "%d", &numberofstud);
    fflush(stdin);
    for(int i=0; i<numberofstud;i++){
        printf("Enter UP Student Number:");
        fgets(info[i].idnum, sizeof info[i].idnum, stdin);
        printf("Enter Name:");
        fgets(info[i].name, sizeof info[i].name, stdin);
        printf("Enter Number of Enrolled Courses:");
        fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
        sscanf(buf, "%d", &info[i].numberofcourses);
        getchar();
        for(int j=0; j<info[i].numberofcourses;j++){
            printf("Enter Course Name:");
            fgets(buf, sizeof info[i].coursename[j], stdin);
            sscanf(buf, "%s", &info[i].coursename[j]);
            printf("Enter Course Units:");
            fgets(buf, sizeof info[i].unit[j], stdin);
            sscanf(buf, "%d", &info[i].unit[j]);
            printf("Enter Course Grade:");
            fgets(buf, 5, stdin);
            sscanf(buf, "%f", &info[i].grade[j]);
            getchar();
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<numberofstud;i++){
    printf("%s", info[i].idnum);
    printf("%s", info[i].name);
        for(int j=0; j<info[i].numberofcourses;j++){
            printf("%s, %d, %.3f", info[i].coursename[j], info[i].unit[j], info[i].grade[j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is an example of what happens when I try to run the program

Sample Output:

```
Enter Number of Students:1
Enter UP Student Number:412412
Enter Name:Martinez
Enter Number of Enrolled Courses:1

Enter Course Name:CMSC 11
Enter Course Units:2
Enter Course Grade:3

412412

CMSC, 2, 3.000
```

I also don't mind if you point out any mistakes or bad practices in my code so that I can keep improving! Thank you for your time.

Comment: tried printing `buf` to see what you're actually reading ?

Comment: Oh, my `buf` overflows. That's a big and obvious mistake. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: You have `char buf[3];` and then do `fgets(buf, sizeof info[i].coursename[j], stdin);` — this is not going to lead to happiness.  You probably need `char buf[32];` or thereabouts, and should then use `sizeof(buf)` in the call to `fgets()`.  Or read direct into `info[i].coursename`, remembering to remove the newline at the end of the string (but then printing a newline when necessary, too).  When you use `sscanf()` with `%s`, you skip blanks and read one word up to the next blank (or end of string).  You should check each and every call to `fgets()` for an error return, too.

Comment: regarding: `sscanf(buf, "%s", &info[i].coursename[j]);`  the field `coursename[j]` is an array.  referencing a 'bare' array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  So `&info[i].coursename[j]` results in the address of an address. (your compiler should have told you about this problem.)  If not, then enable the warnings.

Comment: considering the actual output from your program,  What were you expecting?

Comment: OT:  you could make it much more robust by, when calling `fgets()` with `buf` as the target, to always use: `sizeof( buf )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a newline character in you final print fixed the issue for me. Also [@Jonathan Leffer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler)'s comment is true, you'll likely chop your input or overrun a buffer keeping it so small like that, best to give more room than likely needed if memory space isn't a constraint.

With that said, I cleaned it up a little and added those newlines, the following code appears to function as intended. I also commented out some `getchar` calls and a `fflush`, if those were a mistake to remove I left them in just un-comment them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int   eh;
    char  name[32];
    char  idnum[32];
    char  coursename[9][20];
    int   numberofcourses;
    int   unit[9];
    float grade[9];
}information;

int main(){
    char         id[32];
    char         course_name[12];
    information  info[21];
    char         buf[32]; //Increased your buffer size
    int          numberofstud;
    
    printf("Enter Number of Students:");
    fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
    sscanf(buf, "%d", &numberofstud);
    //fflush(stdin);
    for(int i=0; i<numberofstud;i++){
        printf("Enter UP Student Number:");
        fgets(info[i].idnum,sizeof(info[i].idnum),stdin);
        
        printf("Enter Name:");
        fgets(info[i].name,sizeof(info[i].name),stdin);
        
        printf("Enter Number of Enrolled Courses:");
        fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
        sscanf(buf, "%d", &info[i].numberofcourses);
        //getchar();
        for(int j=0; j<info[i].numberofcourses;j++){
            
            printf("Enter Course Name:");
            fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
            sscanf(buf, "%s", &info[i].coursename[j]);
        
            printf("Enter Course Units:");
            fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
            sscanf(buf, "%d", &info[i].unit[j]);
            
            printf("Enter Course Grade:");
            fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
            sscanf(buf, "%f", &info[i].grade[j]);
            //getchar();
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<numberofstud;i++){
        printf("%s\n", info[i].idnum);
        printf("%s\n", info[i].name);
        for(int j=0; j<info[i].numberofcourses;j++){
            printf("%s, %d, %.3f", info[i].coursename[j], info[i].unit[j], info[i].grade[j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```